# Multiplication in VB6 causing an Overflow Exception - how to resolve?

Tags: vb6, long-integer

In antiquated VB6, I am trying to calculate the free and use disk space:

```
Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpace Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceA" (ByVal lpRootPathName As String, lpSectorsPerCluster As Long, lpBytesPerSector As Long, lpNumberOfFreeClusters As Long, lpTtoalNumberOfClusters As Long) As Long

Dim info As DiskInformation
Dim lAnswer As Long
Dim lpRootPathName As String
Dim lpSectorsPerCluster As Long
Dim lpBytesPerSector As Long
Dim lpNumberOfFreeClusters As Long
Dim lpTotalNumberOfClusters As Long
Dim lBytesPerCluster As Long
Dim lNumFreeBytes As Double
Dim dPercentFreeClusters As Double
Dim sString As String

lpRootPathName = "c:\"
lAnswer = GetDiskFreeSpace(lpRootPathName, lpSectorsPerCluster, lpBytesPerSector, lpNumberOfFreeClusters, lpTotalNumberOfClusters)
lBytesPerCluster = lpSectorsPerCluster * lpBytesPerSector

' Throws overflow exception - I guess there were no Terabyte drives when VB6 came around
lNumFreeBytes = lBytesPerCluster * lpNumberOfFreeClusters
```

> lBytesPerCluster = 4096  |   lpNumberOfFreeClusters = 474304894

I have tried wrapping the multiplication with CLng still get the overflow exception.

How can I resolve `? lBytesPerCluster * lpNumberOfFreeClusters` ??

Comment: Maybe Currency type (`Dim lNumFreeBytes As Currency`), that stores 15 digits, works: `lNumFreeBytes = CCur(lBytesPerCluster) * CCur(lpNumberOfFreeClusters)`

Comment: A long (known as an integer in Windows 32 bit) has a maximum of 2^15 (as one bit is used for =/-) which is 2^31 or 2 gig.

Comment: That's 2^31 I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion to `Variant` data type:

```
Dim v1, v2, v3 As Variant
v1 = lBytesPerCluster
v2 = lpNumberOfFreeClusters

' this now works:
? v1*v2
```

Comment: This works because the internal variable type in v1 and v2 above will be long.  v1*v2 will be Double.  You can see this with the VarType function (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/vartype-function): VarType(v1)=3, VarType(v2)=3, VarType(v1*v2)=5.  You would be be better off to use the explicit variable types and your code will be more readable and maintainable.